# Long to Wide and Duplicate Column when Row has Data

Tags: r, vba, r-table

Wondering how others might tackle this challenge.

**Background**

Data is for vegetation monitoring. It includes basic per plot info and identifies the species and % cover for those species.

There are several rows of plot specific information - date, location, distance followed by species rows. Within the species rows values include the % cover for the species in the plot represented by the column.

A simplified view would be a grid like this:

```
plot        1           4            5
date     5/3/2016     6/20/2016     6/22/2016
location    A           F             K
sp1                    15            30
sp2         5                        100
sp3         T           3             5
```

What I hope to get to is a grid like this which lends itself to csv import into the database (*species % cover requires a reference to the plot info in the RMDB*). *Left-most column = table field names.*

```
plot        1        1          4        4            5          5       5
date     5/3/2016   5/3/2016  6/20/2016 6/20/2016 6/22/2016  6/22/2016 6/22/2016
location    A        A          F        F            K         K        K
species    sp2      sp3        sp1       sp3        sp1        sp2       sp3
cover %     5        T         15        3           30        100       5
```

This wide format can be readily "digested" by the database and properly populate two tables (Plot & CoverPercent).

**Approach?**

I've thought of a couple approaches, but I think there's a better way that I'm missing.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

- Flip the data from long to wide
- Add a `species` and `cover` row
- Count the number of species for a given plot
- Repeat the plot's column based on the number of species
- Populate the plot's 'species' and 'cover' rows

Originally I had thought I could do this in VBA, but it seems perhaps R is a better/faster/cleaner approach. The question though is "how"?

I've done some R work most recently w/ the table package, but I'm certainly rusty having spent the past year on VBA/SQL projects.

**I'm curious how others would approach this change. Any thoughts?**

Comment: Does the database really use a transposed csv like that, or are the column labels on the left of the "wide" example really the headers?

Comment: You're right -- they're the headers on the left (column names). I think I've been staring at this data way too long!

Comment: Is the data currently in an Excel sheet that looks like "simplified view " or coming from somewhere else?  A VBA solution would be really easy - I can't speak to R.

Comment: Yes, it's in an Excel sheet. For some reason my mind has gone on vacation w/r/t a VBA solution and hopped over to R! (Probably because I need to do some R work again soon - w/ tie-ins to Access.) How would you go about the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an OO approach to this.  Define a simple class that holds information about the plot and data and has a dictionary of species and coverage percentages:

```vb
'Plot.cls
Option Explicit

Private Type PlotMembers
    PlotId As Long
    DataDate As Date
    Location As String
End Type

Private this As PlotMembers
Private mCover As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mCover = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub

Public Property Get PlotId() As Long
    PlotId = this.PlotId
End Property

Public Property Let PlotId(inValue As Long)
    this.PlotId = inValue
End Property

Public Property Get DataDate() As Date
    DataDate = this.DataDate
End Property

Public Property Let DataDate(inValue As Date)
    this.DataDate = inValue
End Property

Public Property Get Location() As String
    Location = this.Location
End Property

Public Property Let Location(inValue As String)
    this.Location = inValue
End Property

Public Sub AddSpeciesCover(species As String, cover As String)
    mCover.Add species, cover
End Sub
```

Then give it a property that spits out a list of CSV data rows:

```vb
'Also in Plot.cls
Public Property Get CsvRows() As String
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim output() As String
    ReDim output(mCover.Count - 1)
    Dim i As Long
    For Each key In mCover.Keys
        Dim temp(4) As String
        temp(0) = this.PlotId
        temp(1) = this.DataDate
        temp(2) = this.Location
        temp(3) = key
        temp(4) = mCover(key)
        output(i) = Join(temp, ",")
        i = i + 1
    Next key
    CsvRows = Join(output, vbCrLf)
End Property
```

Then, all you need to do is fill them up from your input data.  Note, the sample usage here assumes that the top grid in your question basically looks like the active sheet with the top left corner at A1.  It should be fairly easy to change this to match how you need to collect the data:

```vb
Public Sub SampleUsage()
    Dim plots As New Collection

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim col As Long
        For col = 2 To 4
            Dim current As Plot
            Set current = New Plot
            current.PlotId = .Cells(1, col).Value
            current.DataDate = .Cells(2, col).Value
            current.Location = .Cells(3, col).Value
            Dim r As Long
            For r = 4 To 6
                Dim cover As String
                cover = .Cells(r, col).Value
                If cover <> vbNullString Then
                    current.AddSpeciesCover .Cells(r, 1).Value, cover
                End If
            Next
            plots.Add current
        Next

    End With

    For Each current In plots
        Debug.Print current.CsvRows
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that this is only a skeleton to demonstrate the gist of the method - it would need error handling, more robust formatting, etc., etc. to be production ready.

Answer (score 1):

Simply reshape your data frame in R using reshape2 package's `melt()` method. Below assumes the transposed view of your posted data is the actual format as you seem to mention in comments:

```r
library(reshape2)

data = 'plot    date    location    sp1 sp2 sp3
1   5/3/2016    A       5   T
4   6/20/2016   F   15      3
5   6/22/2016   K   30  100 5'

df <- read.table(text=data, header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df    
#   plot      date location sp1 sp2 sp3
# 1    1  5/3/2016        A  NA   5   T
# 2    4 6/20/2016        F  15  NA   3
# 3    5 6/22/2016        K  30 100   5

mdf <- melt(df, id.vars=c("plot", "date", "location"),
            variable.name="species", na.rm = TRUE, value.name="cover %")
mdf <- mdf[with(mdf, order(date)),]               # ORDER BY DATE
rownames(mdf) <- seq_len(nrow(mdf))               # RESET ROW NAMES
mdf

#   plot      date location species cover %
# 1    1  5/3/2016        A     sp2       5
# 2    1  5/3/2016        A     sp3       T
# 3    4 6/20/2016        F     sp1      15
# 4    4 6/20/2016        F     sp3       3
# 5    5 6/22/2016        K     sp1      30
# 6    5 6/22/2016        K     sp2     100
# 7    5 6/22/2016        K     sp3       5
```